# sqlite calculate each enter and exit to as one enter

Tags: sql, sqlite, counting

you suppose we have a class and for this class each students can multiple enter and exit and i have store them in database (each enter and each exiting after enter to class), for example:

```
`id`, `student_id`,   `session_id`, `enter`, `exit`, `date_time`

 '1',   '123',          '1',          '1',     '0',     '---',      #enter
 '1',   '123',          '1',          '1',     '1',     '---',      #exit
```

student which that have `123` id entered to class which that's `1` entered to the class and i create row that by `enter = 1 and exit = 0`

after exiting from class i have another new row as `enter = 1 and exit = 1`

i should to have this structure and i can't change them in single row, that means i can't update existing row. now, this student can multiple enter to class and exit after store enter data,

in fact this student only is one person which entered to the class and exited  from specify class, `session_id = 1`, now how can i calculate this operation and getting from database? i don't need to calculate present of students in class and i need to have only count of all student which in multiple enter to class as 1 record

[DB-FILLDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/8) sample sql

Comment: What is the logic behind marking a single row with both enter _and_ exit?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i don't know, server-side developers want me them with this structure

Comment: What database are you using? The title says sqlite, but you tagged both sqlite and mysql. Only tag the one you're actually working with.

Comment: @Shawn that's sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using conditional aggregation, summing the cases where `enter = 1` and `exit = 0` as logins, and the cases where `enter = 1` and `exit = 1` as logouts. You can also simplify your query by writing it as a `JOIN`:

```
select s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type, s.date_time,
       sum(case when b.enter = '1' and b.exit = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as logins,
       sum(case when b.enter = '1' and b.exit = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as logouts,
       sum(case when b.enter = '1' and b.exit = '0' then 1 else 0 end) - sum(case when b.enter = '1' and b.exit = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as person
from sessions s
left join barcodes b on b.session_id = s.id
group by s.id
```

Output:

```
id  session_name    session_type    date_time   logins  logouts person
1   class_a         1               ---         4       2       2
2   class_b         2               ---         2       0       2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/9)

If you just want the number of students (logged in or out) for each session, you can count the distinct barcodes for that session:

```
select s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type, s.date_time,
       count(distinct b.barcode) as person
from sessions s
left join barcodes b on b.session_id = s.id
group by s.id
```

Output:

```
id  session_name    session_type    date_time   person
1   class_a         1               ---         3
2   class_b         2               ---         1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/14)

Comment: i think this query is not correct, because of for `section_id = 1` i have only three student which are in class but i get `2`, correct is `3` and for `section_id = 2` i correct count of student is `1`, i get `0`, you don't neet to calculate each enter or exit to class and i need to have only grouping students count that multiple enter or exit from class as one student https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/12

Comment: I must be misinterpreting your question. Perhaps this is what you want? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/13

Comment: @DolDurma was that comment what you were looking for? If so I'll update the answer so that it is included for anyone else that sees this question.

Comment: yes thanks a lot. i get new update from your comment and my problem solved

Comment: i have a bit problem, could you help me to resolve that? in this link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/16 when i have more `id` with the same data i get wrong result, in this query i must to have `1 - 1`, but i get `2 - 0`

Comment: @DolDurma for your example both barcodes have the same `session_id` value, that is why you are getting 2-0. Why do you think it should be 1-1?

Comment: yes you right, you suppose each student can be participate in some class with the same barcode, for example with `123` barcode, i can participate in class `A` and after that class `B`, and there is a simple tip. in this link. barcodes are different https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/16

Comment: @DolDurma but in the `barcodes` table the `session_id` that each `barcode` refers to is the same (`1`). So I don't see how you expect to have any values for `session_id = 2`?